# SimpleDB: Guaranteed to see all item attributes if we see the item? (non-consistent read)

Tags: nosql, amazon-web-services, amazon-simpledb

I've just discovered an assumption in my use of SimpleDB. I suspect it's safe but would like other opinions since the docs don't seem to cover it.

So say Process 1 stores an item with x attributes. When Process 2 tries to access said item (without consistent read) & finds it, is it guaranteed to have all the attributes stored by Process 1?

I'm excluding the possibility that another process could have changed the data.

I also know that Process 2 has no guarantee of seeing the item unless consistent read is used, I'm just talking about the point when it does eventually see it.

I guess the question is, once I can get an item & am not changing it anywhere else can I assume it has an ad-hoc fixed schema and access all my expected attributes without checking they actually exist?

I don't want to be in a situation where I need to keep requesting items until they have all the attributes I need to use them.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although Amazon makes no such guarantees in the documentation the current implementation of their eventual consistency guarantees that you'll see all the properties stored by Process 1 or none of them.

See [this thread](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=90977) over at the AWS forums and more specifically [this answer](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=90977&#90941) by an Amazon employee confirming the behavior (emphasis mine).

> I don't think we make that guarantee in the documentation, but the
>   **current implementation treats each Put request as a bundle**.  It won't
>   split the request up and apply the operations piecemeal.  You'll get
>   either step-1 responses or step-2 responses until eventual consistency
>   shakes out and leaves you with step-2 responses.

While this is undocumented behavior I suspect quite a few SimpleDB users are relying on it now and as such Amazon won't be likely to change it anytime soon, but that's ju my guess.

Comment: Sorry so long to respond, I thought the question was dead. But thanks for coming back on this - awesome answer, I'll sleep better tonight :)

If they do change this I'd expected it to be an API option, I'd agree it's possible many people rely on this behaviour without realising.

Thanks again!